# Side notes marking multiple lines of text

Tags: footnotes, marginpar, notes, todonotes, marginnote

I am looking for a method to put small side notes next to the text, by simultanously marking the amount of lines to which the note refers. So, something like this:

[image]

I was trying many methods like `todonotes`, `sidenotes`, `marginpar` with `mdframed`, etc. But all packages seem to limit the height depending on the amount of text in the note. And I can only point the note to a specific place in the main text. But I want something that I can point to a specific amount of text or paragraph which also determines the note height.

Comment: Do you need to allow page breaking within the marked region?

Comment: Yes that would be great if possible. But in the case that there is no better solution, I would also be interested in a no-pagebreak solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option using `\tikzmark` (since some calculations are performed for the bar placement, the code needs three runs to stabilize). The bar admits (multiple) page breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,rmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{bordercntr}
\newcounter{borderpages}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[inner xsep=0pt] (#1) {};}

\newenvironment{tikzborder}[2][7pt]
{%
  \gdef\borderspacing{#1}
  \stepcounter{bordercntr}%
  \tikzmark{start-border}\label{start-border\thebordercntr}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,text=gray,font=\footnotesize] at 
  ([xshift=\marginparsep,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.east|-start-border.north)
  {\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\begin{spacing}{0.8}\raggedright#2\end{spacing}}};%
  % if the marks are in the same page, nothing is done
  % otherwise, the decoration is drawn from the starting point to the page bottom
  % and, if necessary, intermediate pages will also receive the decoration
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}=\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr}\else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
         ([xshift=\borderspacing,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.east|-start-border.north) --  
         ([xshift=\borderspacing]current page text area.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\setcounter{borderpages}{\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr}-\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}}%
    \ifnum\value{borderpages}>1\relax
      \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage[#1]}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
\ignorespaces%
}
{\tikzmark{end-border}\label{end-border\thebordercntr}%
  % if the marks are in the same page, the decoration is drawn
  % otherwise, the decoration is drawn from the top of the page to the end mark
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}=\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
         ([xshift=\borderspacing,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.east|-start-border.north) --  
         ([xshift=\borderspacing,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.east|-end-border.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
         ([xshift=\borderspacing]current page text area.north east) --  
         ([xshift=\borderspacing,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.east|-end-border.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi%
}

% the command to draw the decoration in intermediate pages from the top
% to the bottom of the page
\newcommand\tikzborderpage[1][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[ultra thick,gray]
         ([xshift=\borderspacing,yshift=-\baselineskip]current page text area.north east) --  
         ([xshift=\borderspacing,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \addtocounter{borderpages}{-1}%
  \ifnum\value{borderpages}>1
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage[#1]}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzborder}{Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.\end{tikzborder} Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.

\begin{tikzborder}{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.}\lipsum*[1-3]\end{tikzborder}Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The solution uses an environment with a mandatory argument:

```
\begin{tikzborder}{<note>}
<text>
\end{tikzborder}
```

There's also an optional argument to control the separation between the text and the bar.

Here's now a new variation placing the annotations on the outer margin; this is specially useful for two-sided documents (in fact, the code contains the necessary elements for an easy extension admitting outer, left or inner margins):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{bordercntr}
\newcounter{borderpages}

\newcommand\AnnAnchor{north west}
\newcommand\AnnMargin{east}
\newcommand\AnnAlign{\raggedright}
\newlength\AnnSep
\setlength\AnnSep{\marginparsep}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[inner xsep=0pt] (#1) {};}

\newenvironment{tikzborder}[1]
{%
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\renewcommand\AnnAnchor{north west}%
\renewcommand\AnnMargin{east}%
\setlength\AnnSep{\marginparsep}%
\else
\renewcommand\AnnAnchor{north east}%
\renewcommand\AnnMargin{west}%
\setlength\AnnSep{-\marginparsep}%
\renewcommand\AnnAlign{\raggedleft}
\fi%
  \stepcounter{bordercntr}%
  \tikzmark{start-border}\label{start-border\thebordercntr}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=\AnnAnchor,inner sep=0pt,text=gray,font=\footnotesize] at 
  ([xshift=\AnnSep,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.\AnnMargin|-start-border.north)
  {\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\begin{spacing}{0.8}\AnnAlign#1\end{spacing}}};%
  % if the marks are in the same page, nothing is done
  % otherwise, the decoration is drawn from the starting point to the page bottom
  % and, if necessary, intermediate pages will also receive the decoration
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}=\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr}\else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
         ([xshift=0.5\AnnSep,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.\AnnMargin|-start-border.north) --  
         ([xshift=0.5\AnnSep]current page text area.south \AnnMargin);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\setcounter{borderpages}{\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr}-\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}}%
    \ifnum\value{borderpages}>1\relax
      \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage[#1]}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
\ignorespaces%
}
{\checkoddpage%
\ifoddpage
\setlength\AnnSep{\marginparsep}%
\renewcommand\AnnAnchor{north west}%
\renewcommand\AnnMargin{east}%
\else
\setlength\AnnSep{-\marginparsep}%
\renewcommand\AnnAnchor{north east}%
\renewcommand\AnnMargin{west}%
\fi%
\tikzmark{end-border}\label{end-border\thebordercntr}%
  % if the marks are in the same page, the decoration is drawn
  % otherwise, the decoration is drawn from the top of the page to the end mark
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}=\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw [ultra thick,gray]
         ([xshift=0.5\AnnSep,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.\AnnMargin|-start-border.north) --  
         ([xshift=0.5\AnnSep,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.\AnnMargin|-end-border.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
         ([xshift=0.5\AnnSep]current page text area.north \AnnMargin) --  
         ([xshift=0.5\AnnSep,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.\AnnMargin|-end-border.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi%
}

% the command to draw the decoration in intermediate pages from the top
% to the bottom of the page
\newcommand\tikzborderpage[1][0pt]{%
\checkoddpage%
\ifoddpage
\setlength\AnnSep{\marginparsep}%
\renewcommand\AnnAnchor{north west}%
\renewcommand\AnnMargin{east}%
\else
\setlength\AnnSep{-\marginparsep}%
\renewcommand\AnnAnchor{north east}%
\renewcommand\AnnMargin{west}%
\fi%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[ultra thick,gray]
         ([xshift=0.5\AnnSep,yshift=-\baselineskip]current page text area.north \AnnMargin) --  
         ([xshift=0.5\AnnSep,yshift=0.65ex]current page text area.south \AnnMargin);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \addtocounter{borderpages}{-1}%
  \ifnum\value{borderpages}>1
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage[#1]}%
  \fi%
}

\title{Some Title}
\author{Some Author}

\begin{document}
.\clearpage%just for the example

\begin{tikzborder}{Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.\end{tikzborder} Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.

\begin{tikzborder}{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.}\lipsum*[1-7]\end{tikzborder}Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.

\lipsum*[1-2]\begin{tikzborder}{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.}\lipsum*[3-5]\end{tikzborder}\lipsum[2]

\lipsum*[3-4]\begin{tikzborder}{Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.}\lipsum*[4-8]\end{tikzborder}\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting but I don't have time to study the solution. Am I right in assuming that you assume a non-symmetric page design? If so, is there a way to generalise the solution and force the line in the outer (or inner) margin for symmetric page designs?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen in it's current form, the text is always typeset in the left margin using a box of width equal to `\marginparwidth`; and yes, the solution can be generalized to use the outer (or inner) margin. Perhaps I'll do this.

Comment: +1 (I should have put money on you or Andrew posting a tikzmark solution to this:-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks for your code. I have three questions on that solution:
(1) What is the package `atbegshi` for? I tested your solution and it worked without that package.
(2) I like to decrease the line height, but could not find the right place in the tiksborder definition where to add `\begin{spacing}{0.5} ... \end{spacing}`
(3) Your method only places the notes on the right side. I use twosided `scrreprt`, is it possible to adapt on that easily?

Comment: @Martin You're welcome! Regarding your questions, (1) `atbegshi` provides the command `\AtBeginShipoutNext` which will be used when the vertical rule should span more than two consecutive pages; in my example this doesn't happen, so you can comment out the package without problems, but if you change `\lipsum*[1-3]` to `\lipsum*[1-30]` you will need the package. (2) Perhaps I don't understand. Are you trying to decrease the separation between consecutive lines in the text used for the annotations? (Cont.)

Comment: @Martin  (3) Easily, yes; however, it requires time and I don't have much free time these days. I'll try to produce the code in the following days.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Great, many thanks. (3) Please do not hurry. (2) Yes, it is just for a better look & style. In this case of small-fontsized sidenotes, the line separation should be small, too. I thought it is easy to include the additional environment into your framework, surrounding the actual text, but I cannot find out the proper position.

Comment: @Martin I've added the code using the `setspace` package to reduce the inter-line spacing for the annotations. As soon as I have time, I'll tackle number (3) :-)

Comment: @Martin I've made a new update; the last example code in my answer contains the settings for placement in the outer margins.

Comment: I am delighted! Thanks a lot, please tell me if you have a Beer-Donation account ([link](http://www.beerdonation.com)) :-)