# How can I accomplish similar side notes?

Tags: marginnote, notes

I would like to add side notes to my document as in the example below, but I do not know how. I will be grateful for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Side notes marking multiple lines of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118682/side-notes-marking-multiple-lines-of-text). It is not exactly what you've asked, but Gonzalo's answer should help you to go some steps and show us a [minimal but working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of your suggestion, if you need more help.

Comment: The `todonotes` package does something very similar.

Answer (score 3):

A default `\todo` from the `todonotes` package does something similar to what you're asking, so if you're not using `todonotes` already, the following might be useful.

`\todo` does draw a coloured box around the margin note, but changing the `bordercolor` and `backgroundcolor` as below removes that.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
 bordercolor=none,
 backgroundcolor=none,
 linecolor=gray
]{todonotes}
\begin{document}
Bla bla etc., uzw., osb., Lorem ipsum dolor \todo{Foo bar}{} and so on and so forth.
\end{document}
```

It's possible to redefine some macros to get output more like your image.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
 bordercolor=none,
 backgroundcolor=none,
 linecolor=gray
]{todonotes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  smallcirc/.tip={Circle[width=2pt,length=2pt]},
  % connectstyle is used for the line drawing to the marginnote,
  % add the arrow tip on each end, and make it thin
  connectstyle/.append style={smallcirc-smallcirc,thin}
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawLineToRightMargin}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[connectstyle]%
(inText) -- ([yshift=-0.2cm] inText)% %% <--- added "(intext) --"
-| (inNote.west);% %% <--- removed "-| ([xshift=-0.2cm] inNote.west)"
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawLineToLeftMargin}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[connectstyle]%
(inText) -- ([yshift=-0.2cm] inText)% %% <--- added "(intext) --"
-| (inNote.west);% %% <--- removed "-| ([xshift=-0.2cm] inNote.west)"
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Bla bla etc., uzw., osb., Lorem ipsum dolor \todo{Foo bar}{} and so on and so forth.
\end{document}
```